# Liquid metal node setup

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I'm trying to create a node setup for a liquid metal like material similar to this, but even after hours of trying, I'm nowhere near. Can anyone give me any advice on how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Just a fancy normal map, I'd say. What you've tried so far exactly? Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like fun.

1. Plug a *Musgrave texture* into another *Musgrave texture* :).
2. Conect it as a *Displacement*
3. Lighting is rather important, [I used this free HDRI](https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?h=venice_sunset)
4. (optional)(Add a Dreamstime watermark)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Absolutely fantastic - just what I needed! Many thanks, Jachym!

Comment: Glad to be of help :). Good luck with your project.

Comment: It's going to be on a book cover. Soon in a bookstore near you :D The title is Star Trek Voyager: Nehodni.

Comment: Oh, that's so cool! :). If you get stuck somewhere, I can send over the .blend. Bye.

Comment: Loved that add dreamstime watermark :P

Comment: @PrakharLondhe Thanks. God is in the details :)